# Virtual host not working in Windows 7 XAMPP

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I am using Windows 7 and XAMPP. I want to create a virtual host so I added

```
127.0.0.1       myawesomeproject
```

to my hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) like this:

```
    # Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
    #
    # This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
    #
    # This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
    # entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
    # be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
    # The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
    # space.
    #
    # Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
    # lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
    #
    # For example:
    #
    #      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
    #       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

    # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
        127.0.0.1       localhost
        127.0.0.1       myawesomeproject
        ::1             localhost
```

and I added some lines to my XAMPP vhosts configuration file (C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf) like this:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.localhost"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.localhost"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
   </VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin awesome@myawesomeproject.com
    DocumentRoot c:\myawesomeproject
    ServerName localhost

<Directory "c:\myawesomeproject">
    Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I created a folder called `myawesomeproject` on my C drive. When I type

```
http://myawesomeproject
```

it is redirecting to

```
http://myawesomeproject/xampp
```

I added another folder `'test'` inside `myawesomeproject`, so the path to `'test'`  is `C:/myawesomeproject/test`.

The problem is, when I type `http://myawesomeproject/test` it gives an error. It says

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
myawesomeproject
8/22/2011 4:30:29 PM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Why is this? How can I create a virtual host?

Answer (score 3):

Given the configuration you describe I'm sort of surprised that you apache is starting. Try configuring your hosts file like this

```
    127.0.0.1    localhost myawesomeproject.com
```

then tidy up your vhosts like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin awesome@myawesomeproject.com
    DocumentRoot C:\myawesomeproject
    ServerName myawesomeproject.com

    <Directory "C:\myawesomeproject">
        Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This should direct traffic for `http://myawesomeproject.com` to C:\myawesomeproject and traffic for `http://localhost` to C:\xampp\htdocs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. 
You have to uncomment the line with

## NameVirtualHost *

Once I uncomment and restarted apache at xampp control pannel, it started working